# vagrant login as root by default

Tags: authentication, ssh, vagrant, root

Problem: frequently the first command I type to my boxes is `su -`.

Question: how do I make `vagrant ssh` use the root user by default?

Version: vagrant 1.6.5

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**Solution:** 
Add the following to your `Vagrantfile`:

```ruby
config.ssh.username = 'root'
config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

When you `vagrant ssh` henceforth, you will login as `root` and should expect the following:

```
==> mybox: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    mybox: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    mybox: SSH username: root
    mybox: SSH auth method: password
    mybox: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    mybox: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> mybox: Inserting Vagrant public key within guest...
==> mybox: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> mybox: Machine booted and ready!
```

**Update 23-Jun-2015:**
This works for version 1.7.2 as well. Keying security has improved since 1.7.0; this technique overrides back to the previous method which uses a known private key. This solution is not intended to be used for a box that is accessible publicly without proper security measures done prior to publishing.

**Reference:**

- **https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html**

Comment: Could there be any reason to getting the password prompt when running `vagrant ssh`? (after making the described changes) Vagrant version 1.7.2

Comment: @RobertIgnat possibly that you need to set your root passwd to match what you have in your `config.ssh.password` value. you should be able to comment out the newly added `config.ssh.*` lines to access your box and then change the root password via `sudo passwd root`.

Comment: For a machine which has already been provisioned, do the above, and do `mkdir -m 700 /root/.ssh && cp ~vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh`

Comment: doesn't work for a fresh Vagrant install, probably because when one uses e.g. ubuntu/xenial, one HAS to use the user logins baked there. (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40478402/605463)

Comment: For anyone else using `centos/7`: This box sets a random root password; one can `vagrant ssh` and then `sudo su` to root, but (from what I can tell) the config settings don't work on a fresh `vagrant up` using this VM.

Answer (score 172):

This is useful:

```bash
sudo passwd root
```

for anyone who's been caught out by the need to set a root password in vagrant first

Comment: Saved my life. Do you know if this has any repercussions with how vagrant acts?

Comment: Lesson here is that if you create a base box, follow the conventions suggested by Hashicorp and set your root passwd to 'vagrant'. see http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes/base.html

Comment: Are there any potential security issues with a server that has a really easily guessed root password lying around on your personal computer, though? I imagine the network settings help with this, but I wonder.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It turns out that Ubuntu's vagrant boxes set a random password for the root user (See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vagrant-up/xMWKkKW24xs/f5OaV5QWAp4J). So one always has to set a root password first.

Answer (score 45):

This works if you are on ubuntu/trusty64 box:

```bash
vagrant ssh
```

Once you are in the ubuntu box:

```bash
sudo su
```

Now you are root user. You can update root password as shown below:

```bash
sudo -i
passwd
```

Now edit the below line in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```sshconfig
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Also, it is convenient to create your own alternate username:

```bash
adduser johndoe
```

Wait until it asks for password.

Answer (score 16):

If `Vagrantfile` as below:

```ruby
config.ssh.username = 'root'
config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

But vagrant still ask you root password, 
most likely the base box you used do not configured to allow root login.

---

For example, the offical ubuntu14.04 box do not set  `PermitRootLogin yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

So If you want a box can login as root default(only Vagrantfile, no more work), you have to :

1. Setup a vm by username `vagrant`(whatever name but root)
2. Login and edit sshd config file.

   ubuntu: edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, set  `PermitRootLogin yes`

   others: ....

   (I only use ubuntu, feel free to add workaround of other platforms)
3. Build a new base box:

   ```bash
   vagrant package --base your-vm-name
   ```

   this create a file `package.box`
4. Add that base box to vagrant:

   ```bash
   vagrant box add ubuntu-root file:///somepath/package.box
   ```

   then, you need use this base box to build vm which allow auto login as root.
5. Destroy original vm by `vagrant destroy`
6. Edit original `Vagrantfile`, change box name to `ubuntu-root` and username to `root`, then `vagrant up` create a new one.

It cost me some time to figure out , it is too complicate in my opinion. Hope vagrant would improve this.

Answer (score 12):

Dont't forget root is allowed root to login before!!!

Place the config code below in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

```sshconfig
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please add enough details and context to answers. Especially when answering old question with some good answers

Comment: this was more useful for me than the main solution. ssh doesn't let you login as root by default.

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** Only use this method for local development, **it's not secure**.
You can setup password and ssh config while provisioning the box. For example with `debian/stretch64` box this is my provision script:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    echo -e "vagrant\nvagrant" | passwd root
    echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    sed -in 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    service ssh restart
SHELL
```

This will set root password to `vagrant` and permit root login with password. If you are using `private_network` say with ip address `192.168.10.37` then you can ssh with `ssh root@192.168.10.37`

You may need to change that `echo` and `sed` commands depending on the default `sshd_config` file.

Comment: instead of adding the option to the end, I would prefer `sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 7):

Adding this to the `Vagrantfile` worked for me. These lines are the equivalent of you entering `sudo su -` every time you login. Please notice that this requires reprovisioning the VM.

```ruby
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "sudo su -" >> .bashrc
SHELL
```

Comment: Thanks for your very simple solution!

    echo "sudo -s" >> .bashrc would be better.

Comment: @Honiix You mean `-i`? 

Comment: @ThomasGotwig you're right, ` -i ` is more common than ` -s `, both works depending on what you want to do. But my point was that it is best to avoid chaining sudo and su.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but looking at the original question, it looks like the user just wanted to run a command as root, that's what I need to do when I was searching for an answer and stumbled across the question.

So this one is worth knowing in my opinion:

```bash
vagrant ssh servername -c "echo vagrant | sudo -S shutdown 0"
```

`vagrant` is the password being echoed into the the sudo command, because as we all know, the vagrant account has sudo privileges and when you sudo, you need to specify the password of the user account, not root..and of course by default, the vagrant user's password is `vagrant` !

By default you need root privileges to shutdown so I guess doing a shutdown is a good test.

Obviously you don't need to specify a server name if there is only one for that vagrant environment. Also, we're talking about local vagrant virtual machine to the host, so there isn't really any security issue that I can see.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had some troubles with provisioning when trying to login as root, even with `PermitRootLogin yes`. I made it so only the `vagrant ssh` command is affected:

```
# Login as root when doing vagrant ssh
if ARGV[0]=='ssh'
  config.ssh.username = 'root'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used vagrant putty with the vagrant multi putty plugin, it took me directly to root.

Answer (score 0):

this may help along answering how to allow root access, as well as password based access to vagrant.

the official image by debian (latest stable debian 12 bookworm) does not include permission for root login as well as password based authentication.

there are a few configurations that will affect connectivity, such as insert key (not needed; default is fine), the ssh.username and ssh.password should not be set as it will default to password based auth when trying to spin up the instance. Contrary to the above, it seems like newer vagrant versions do not timeout; we will get the following error instead.

```
    single: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    single: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    single: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.
...
```

the following is configured in Vagrantfile.

```
# note that the following few settings (insert key, username, password) can/needs to be omitted.
# config.ssh.insert_key = false
# config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
# config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'

config.vm.box = "debian/bookworm64"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-'SHELL'
  sed -i 's/^#* *\(PermitRootLogin\)\(.*\)$/\1 yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  sed -i 's/^#* *\(PasswordAuthentication\)\(.*\)$/\1 yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  systemctl restart sshd.service
  echo -e "vagrant\nvagrant" | (passwd vagrant)
  echo -e "root\nroot" | (passwd root)
SHELL
```

hope it helps.

with kudos to a similar issue reference : [How to enable password ssh authentication for Vagrant VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841206/how-to-enable-password-ssh-authentication-for-vagrant-vm)

Comment: Hey don't completely understand your answer. I have the problem that I can't start debian/bookworm64 with vagrant but the same Vagrantfile works for ubuntu/focal64. How can you provision the vm with shell, if we can`t boot up the vm?

Answer (score -11):

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up
```

Please add this to vagrant file:

```
config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

Comment: This does nothing since the default user is already *vagrant*.

Comment: instead of using config.ssh.username = 'vagrant' .... use config.ssh.username = 'root' .... this will help.