# Unable to connect as the root user in Vagrant 1.7.1

Tags: passwords, vagrant, virtualbox, root

I've been trying to login to Vagrant as a root user using 'vagrant' as the password. It doesn't seem to work. I have checked the official documentation and read few posts which confirm 'vagrant' as the password for the root user. Is there a solution?

Comment: I think this topic can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758737/vagrant-login-as-root-by-default

Answer (score 0):

You should never log in with the root user.  Do everything you need under **sudo** or, worst, **sudo -s**.