# How to enable password ssh authentication for Vagrant VM?

Tags: ssh, passwords, vagrant

I'd like to enable password ssh authentication (and keep key-based authentication enabled) for may Vagrant VM. How to set that?

`Vagrantfile`:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "fedora/26-cloud-base"
  config.vm.box_version = "20170705"

  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'a'
  config.ssh.keys_only = false
end
```

```
$ sudo vagrant ssh-config 
Host default
  HostName 192.168.121.166
  User vagrant
  Port 22
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/jakub/src/kubernetes-vms/kubernetes/.vagrant/machines/default/libvirt/private_key
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Password `a` is not accepted with this settings.

I guess the might be `PasswordAuthentication no` in output of `vagrant ssh-config`. How can that option be switched on?

Answer (score 16):

On centos 7, using only below is not enough. By this way, I guess that it just make `su vagrant` become by password. I cannot find anything why below does not work in the [official site](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html).

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
end
```

You should modify sshd_config manually.

```rb
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
     sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config    
     systemctl restart sshd.service
  SHELL
```

Answer (score 12):

For me the following works. You need to ssh to the vm as usual and then edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. There you need to set `PasswordAuthentication` to `yes` instead of `no`. This will allow password authentication.

Comment: It Works! Thanks

Comment: is there a proper way to script this in ''Vagrantfile'' rather than manually configuring ssh? Btw.: You also need to restart sshd after the change (i.e. systemctl restart sshd)

Comment: I would add `perl -i -pe 'if (/^PasswordAuthentication no$/) { s/no$/yes/; $pwdAuth = 1 ; }; if (/^PasswordAuthentication yes$/) { $pwdAuth = 1 } ; END { if (!$pwdAu
th) {print "\n# activate password auth\nPasswordAuthentication yes\n"}}' /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and the sshd restart command to your provision script

Answer (score 6):

`Vagrantfile`:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "fedora/26-cloud-base"
  config.vm.box_version = "20170705"

  config.vm.provision 'shell', inline: 'echo "vagrant:a" | chpasswd'
end
```

Line `config.vm.provision 'shell', inline: 'echo "vagrant:a" | chpasswd'` invokes shell provisioning that changes password of `vagrant` user (provided the box comes with predefined user called `vagrant`).

Then one can connect not only by `vagrant ssh` but also

```
ssh vagrant@<vm-ip>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to force password authentication for the VM, you would need to set the following from your Vagrantfile

```
  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

You need to make sure the `vagrant` user in the VM has the corresponding password. I am not sure for the box you use so you'll need to verify yourself. It works for following box: `ubuntu/trusty64`

Comment: It didn't work for me. `vagrant up` command got stuck prompting `vagrant@192.168.121.171's password:`. I can't provide the password since it is not provided by the box author.

Comment: so you need to login once to the VM and set the password, then repackage the box and use the config from my post

Comment: maybe, according to https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/61060/252780 it looks like one can't have different account and ssh passwords. I wasn't able to change account password using `config.ssh.password` during my experiments. So I'm really confused about the purpose of `config.ssh.password`.

Comment: you're confusing the authentication and the setting of the password. You need to have the user correctly setup already in the VM (with a password) and `config.ssh.password` is there to let vagrant knows which password is needed to authenticate the user. It is not there to set a new password for the user (you would first need to login to the VM to make this change)

Answer (score 3):

To ssh with password, this will automatically update the sshd config on debian/stretch64:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  sed -i 's/ChallengeResponseAuthentication no/ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config    
  service ssh restart
SHELL
```

Comment: Although the tip of changing the sshd_config helped, when i added the piece of config you mentioned here did not work. After the vm was up, i logged in and changed manually. I had to use sudo sed ..... . I am not sure why sudo is required but thats how i got it working

Answer (score 3):

With the following you enable password ssh authentication for a linux VM and (if you wish) you can also set the password for the users `vagrant` and `root`

```sh
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/bullseye64"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-'SHELL'
    sed -i 's/^#* *\(PermitRootLogin\)\(.*\)$/\1 yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    sed -i 's/^#* *\(PasswordAuthentication\)\(.*\)$/\1 yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    systemctl restart sshd.service
    echo -e "vagrant\nvagrant" | (passwd vagrant)
    echo -e "root\nroot" | (passwd root)
  SHELL
end
```