# Vagrant ssh using ubuntu default user

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

Every time I use vagrant ssh I have to use sudo su ubuntu to switch user. I followed this post [vagrant login as root by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758737/vagrant-login-as-root-by-default/40478402#40478402). It does not work if I replace root with ubuntu. What am I doing wrong? I gives me permissions denied. (public key)

Comment: which box are you using ? is the ubuntu user created on the box or the vm ?

Comment: I am using virtual box and I believe ubuntu user is already created. I can login through default user after the vm has been provisioned but I wish to automatically ssh through vagrant ssh

Answer (score 0):

You can solve in multiple ways:

1. Change the line `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Add `sudo su` in `.bashrc` for ubuntu user

Comment: can i configure something on vagrant level?

Comment: Looks like it's a box (ubuntu defaults) restriction. Vagrant settings can't help here

Answer (score 0):

Putting everything together

- 1) Edit the `/home/vagrant/.bashrc` file, add `sudo su` at the end.
  This will make the shell switch to the `root` user when you log in.
- 2) Edit the `/root/.bashrc` file and add `su ubuntu`. This will make 
  the `root` user switch to `ubuntu`.

Now, when you do `vagrant ssh`, it will effectively log you in as `ubuntu`